# How Many Ways to get N by adding k integers ?

Tags: number-theory

I know the number of ways getting $ n $ by adding k integers is  $ \binom{N-1}{k-1} $ . Now I have applied this theory to the following problem but could not get the correct answer . Why ?

```
I have N coins having values 1,2,3, … N. I have to select a subset of 
exactly K coins from those such that the selected coins sum to N.  How many 
ways can I do it ?
```

According to my theory for N = 8 and k=3 the answer of the above problem is $ \binom{8-1}{3-1} $ . But the answer is 2 .For  N=8, K=3 I can select coins in 2 ways: {1,2,5}, {1,3,4}. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There indeed $\binom72=21$ ways to get $8$ as the sum of three positive integers:

$$\begin{array}{}
6+1+1&1+6+1&1+1+6\\
5+2+1&5+1+2&2+5+1&2+1+5&1+5+2&1+2+5\\
4+3+1&4+1+3&3+4+1&3+1+4&1+4+3&1+3+4\\
4+2+2&2+4+2&2+2+4\\
3+3+1&3+1+3&1+3+3
\end{array}$$

Notice first that we’re keeping track of the order of the terms, so that $4+3+1$ and $1+3+4$ are counted separately; in your problem the order of the coins is irrelevant, and that’s just the single solution $\{1,3,4\}$. Moreover, we’re allowing the same number to be used more than once; in the coin problem that’s not possible, because you have only one of each coin.

In other words, you’re applying a formula for one kind of problem to a very different kind of problem.

Comment: Yes . I have got your point . But to achieve insight of coin problem how can I proceed ?

Comment: @OchenaPothik: Do you have reason to believe that there is a nice answer?

Comment: I have come to know that integer partitions concept can give insight of coin problem . But alas , there is no close form of integer partitions .

Comment: Yes . I have strong belief that there is a nice answer . Because this problem is solved by many one and I want to be one of them .

Comment: @OchenaPothik: I don’t immediately see a nice approach, but I’ll give it some thought. If $f(n,k)$ is the number of solutions, there might, for instance, be some nice recurrences.

Comment: @OchenaPothik What does "solved by many one" mean?  Why do you think that there is a nice answer?

Comment: @user33433: Read it as *solved by many people*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Which people?

Comment: @user33433: I’m not the person to ask, and in fact I have no idea. I don’t even know if the assertion is true. I do, however, know what it means.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, I see—sorry, I was confusing you with the OP.  I'm just curious if there's somebody with an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the coins problem is the coefficient of $X^N Y^k$ in the following product:

$$(1+XY)(1+X^2Y)(1+X^3Y)\ldots (1+X^NY)$$

I think that this number probably has some combinatorially interesting properties, but I would be very surprised it has a closed-form answer.